# How do I trigger a checkbox with code in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tkinter, checkbox

I have been making a `GUI` with `Tkinter` in Python 2.7 and I want to trigger the `checkbox`  from within the code such that the checkbox get ticked whenever that function is read. For e.g Suppose I am reading a `list` of strings and whenever I come across a word in the list called `enable` I need to trigger that definite `checkbox` from an `array` of other checkboxes, such that it gets ticked; so whenever I run the program that checkbox, from an array of other checkboxes, is ticked.
For now what this checkbox is doing if we check it it sends out the value enabled or disabled to the function `force_download_function(i, var.get())`. But I also want to make sure if we are reading from a list and we come across the word 'enabled' it shows a tick on that checkbox number equivalent to the index of the word 'enabled'

```
def make_force_download_button(i):
    var = StringVar()
    force_download_button_array[i] = Checkbutton(top, variable=var, onvalue='enabled', offvalue='disabled', command=lambda: force_download_function(i, var.get()))
    force_download_button_array[i].deselect()

    force_download_button_array[i].pack()
    force_download_button_array[i].place(height=30, width=30, x=420, y=(65 + ((i - 1) * 60)))
```

Comment: You can use `select()` to check the checkbutton and `deselect()` to uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

The code below assumes that you are looping through a list of words with a corresponding index as you stated. I use python 3 so the syntax may differ some.

```py
list_of_words = ["disabled", "enabled", "disabled"]

for num in range(len(list_of_words)):
    if list_of_words[num] == "enabled":
        force_download_button_array[num].select()
    elif list_of_words[num] == "disabled":
        force_download_button_array[num].deselect()
```